# Android: Method is called twice if imeOptions is used

Tags: android, android-activity, ime

Layout:

```
    ....
    <EditText
        ....
        android:hint="@string/email"
        android:imeOptions="actionSend"/>
    <Button
        ...
        android:onClick="sendMessage"      <<<- both must call it 
        android:text="@string/send" />
```

Then binding in code:

```
( (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email) ).setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener()  {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView arg0, int arg1, KeyEvent arg2) {
                sendMessage(findViewById(android.R.id.content));
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Where sendMessage is

```
public void sendMessage(View view)
{
    ....
    intent.putExtra("email", getEditContent(R.id.email));   
    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
}
```

When I press button everything is fine. When I press "Done" in imeOption (keyboard) two Activities starts at the same time.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried changing the return value from `false` to `true`?

Comment: @HugoHidekiYamashita, ha! That works. Post it as a separate answer, please. But that's quite strange for me because, as far as I understand: that means "run default handler or not" (in other words, "was it handeled here _fully_ or not"). But if I leave the OnEditorActionListener unimplemented - nothing happens at all! (I mean, nothing is called by default, so default handler must do nothing). Thank you, anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the return value of the `onEditorAction` method from `true` to `false`.

Actually, I think the method is called twice because of the `KeyEvent`. Try logging the type of the `arg2` parameter to check it. If you confirm this, instead of returning `false`, you can add an if/else to check the correct event.

Answer (score 1):

Chances are that your listener is receiving two different events. Try and debug `onEditorAction` method to check the values of `KeyEvent arg2`, to call your `sendMessage` method in the right event.

Answer (score 1):

```
public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() != KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
        return false;

    // do your stuff

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Please do not provide code-only answers, but also explain how and why your code solved the problem.